# Adding Parcel IDs to Address Data Points upon creation using Parcel Polygons

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, polygon, address

I'm looking for a solution to help automate some of my workflow. Currently when we create an Address Data Point (ADP) we have to manually copy and paste the Parcel ID from our parcels layer into the appropriate field within the ADP layer.

Is there a way I can have that field auto-populated upon creation when a ADP is created inside of a parcel polygon?

We currently use ArcMap for addressing.

Comment: You could do a spatial join (which creates a new feature class), and then join your ADP layer to the new spatil-joined-layer (use OBJECTID field in the ADP layer and Target_FID field in the spatial join layer).  Then Field Calculator to copy the value of the Parcel ID from the spatial-join field to the ADP field.  Then remove the join and (optionally) delete the spatial-join feaure class.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Attribute Assistant. It's a free add-on for ArcMap that can do exactly this. It's a bit involved to set it up, but once that's done one time, it works quite well for this kind of thing.

There is no Attribute Assistant for Pro, however. It was phased out in favor of attribute rules, which are powerful, but can only be used if the database in question is never going to be edited in ArcMap. So any workflows that you set up in Attribute Assistant would have to be re-engineered from scratch when you make the leap to doing that work in Pro.